# Undefined reference errors in Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, ld, undefined-reference, vtable

I have a library and example application, driven by CMake. So, there is a class, which I use in library:

**sourceeditor.h**

```
#ifndef SOURCEEDITOR_H
#define SOURCEEDITOR_H

#include <QWidget>
#include "novile_export.h"

namespace Novile
{

class SourceEditorPrivate;
class NOVILE_EXPORT SourceEditor : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SourceEditor(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~SourceEditor();

private:
    SourceEditorPrivate * const d;

};

} // namespace Novile

#endif // SOURCEEDITOR_H
```

**sourceeditor.cpp**

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QWebView>
#include "novile_debug.h"
#include "sourceeditor.h"

namespace Novile
{

class SourceEditorPrivate
{
public:
    SourceEditorPrivate(SourceEditor *p = 0) :
        parent(p),
        aceView(new QWebView(p)),
        layout(new QVBoxLayout(p))
    {
        parent->setLayout(layout);
        layout->addWidget(aceView);
    }

    ~SourceEditorPrivate()
    {
    }

    void loadAceView()
    {
        aceView->load(QUrl("qrc:/ace.html"));
    }

private:
    SourceEditor *parent;
    QWebView *aceView;
    QVBoxLayout *layout;
};

SourceEditor::SourceEditor(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    d(new SourceEditorPrivate(this))
{
    mDebug() << "Source Editor has been started";

    d->loadAceView();
}

SourceEditor::~SourceEditor()
{
}

} // namespace Novile
```

and example:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "../src/sourceeditor.cpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Novile::SourceEditor editor;
    editor.setGeometry(100, 50, 600, 300);
    editor.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Then I receive a lot of `ld` errors:

```
CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Novile::SourceEditor::SourceEditor(QWidget*)':
../src/sourceeditor.cpp:39: undefined reference to `vtable for Novile::SourceEditor'
../src/sourceeditor.cpp:39: undefined reference to `vtable for Novile::SourceEditor'
CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Novile::SourceEditor::~SourceEditor()':
../src/sourceeditor.cpp:46: undefined reference to `vtable for Novile::SourceEditor'
../src/sourceeditor.cpp:46: undefined reference to `vtable for Novile::SourceEditor'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This file (main.cpp) represents example application, which should test core functionality of library.

Comment: Show us `sourceeditor.h` as well, please.

Comment: You're probably missing a `Q_OBJECT` macro, but since you're not showing the definition of the `SourceEditor` class, hard to tell.

Comment: @Mat header was added

Comment: @AndyProwl private class (some kind of pimpl)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely due to the fact that you are `#include`ing a `.cpp` file:

```
#include "../src/sourceeditor.cpp"
```

You shouldn't do that, and you don't need it. Just include the corresponding header `sourceeditor.h` and, if needed, the `novile_debug.h` header.

Then, make sure both `main.cpp` and `sourceeditor.cpp` are part of your project, so that the compiler will process both these translation units and the linker will eventually merge the corresponding object code into the executable of your program.

Comment: The problem is I don't have hpp file and I need code from .cpp file, too. There are library and example executable (main.cpp)

Comment: @IllyaKovalevskyy: Sorry, I meant `sourceeditor.h`, the header file you have.

Comment: Then I have errors because I haven't included implementation, which is stored in .cpp

Comment: @IllyaKovalevskyy: What implementation? What errors are you getting? You should never `#include` a `.cpp` file